# Перебрать все элементы на странице с определённым классом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не подскажите, как можно перебрать все элементы с классом "product" и если в product содержится add-cart-2, то в нём скрыть add-cart.  Пример кода :

```
<div class="product">
 <div class="add-cart">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="product">
 <div class="add-cart">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="product">
 <div class="add-cart">
 </div>
 <div class="add-cart-2">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а что конкретно вы хотите найти - какая разница что вложено в product?

Comment: Если есть  <div class="add-cart-2"> сюда добавляю данные из корзины (В корзине 10 шт )  , то скрыть  <div class="add-cart">.( Купить )  , что было не было двух кнопок В корзине  и Купить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте это

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('.product').each(function () {

        if($(this).find('.add-cart-2').length){

            $(this).find('.add-cart').hide();

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! идеально то что надо

Comment: @Kirill вы можете закрыть вопрос, нажав на галочку слева от ответа, если этот ответ решает вашу проблему

Comment: Спасибо большое. Закрыл вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное поздновато но

```
$(function() {
    $('.product > .add-cart+.add-cart-2').parent().find('.add-cart').hide();
});
```